# simplify if logic in declaration statement

Tags: c, pic

is there possible to simplify this statement ?

There are same if I using the case statement and while loop.

```
// Led Binary
         if (volt == 0 )
         {
             LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
         }
         else if (volt == 2 )
         {
             LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 On
             LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
         }
         else if (volt == 3 )
         {
             LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 On
             LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 On
             LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
         }
         else if (volt == 4 )
         {
             LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 On
             LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
         }
         else if (volt == 5 )
         {
             LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 On
             LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 On
             LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
         }
         else if (volt == 6 )
         {
            LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
            LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 On
            LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 On
            LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF

         }
         else if (volt == 7 )
         {
             LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 On
             LATGbits.LATG0    = 0 ; //DO2 On
             LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 On
             LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
         }
         else if (volt == 8 )
         {
             LATGbits.LATG1    = 0 ; //DO1 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 On
         }
         else if (volt == 9 )
         {
             LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 On
             LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG13   = 1 ; //DO3 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG14   = 0 ; //DO4 On
         }
         else if (volt == 10 )
         {
             LATGbits.LATG1    = 1 ; //DO1 On
             LATGbits.LATG0    = 1 ; //DO2 OFF
             LATGbits.LATG13   = 0 ; //DO3 On
             LATGbits.LATG14   = 1 ; //DO4 OFF
         }
```

from above code show when some volt is reached, the LED will turn ON or OFF. the code also have many declaration on LED output. Some LED also I declare using Bitwise funtion, but it is same.

thanks.

Comment: My be take a `1` byte variable, and set bits for the corresponding `LED`s

Comment: it seems, from the posted code, that some of the outputs directly set the associated led on and some of the outputs are inverted.  A comment or three, in the code would greatly simplify that info.  Which would make debugging much easier

Comment: Answers depend on definition of the type of `LATGbits`. Please add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use a lookup table to convert the `volt` value to a four-bit LED value, and then use bitwise operators to set each LED output

```
static const int ledTable[16] = { 14, 14, 12, 13, 10, 11, 8, 9, 6, 7, 11, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14 };

int value = ledTable[volt];
LATGbits.LATG1  = value & 1;
LATGbits.LATG0  = (value >> 1) & 1;
LATGbits.LATG13 = (value >> 2) & 1;
LATGbits.LATG14 = (value >> 3) & 1;
```

You can also determine the LED value mathematically, e.g.

```
int value = volt ^ 14;
```

Comment: can I now what does `{ 14, 14, 12, 13, 10, 11, 8, 9, 6, 7, 11, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14 }` means ? why `14,14,12,14 ...`

Answer (score 0):

given the outputs seem to count from 0...14 and are not 'in order',  suggest defining a short int as the 'image' of the current state of the outputs.  Then define a table that has the appropriate bit pattern in each entry for the outputs.  (in this case maybe 11 entries needed)  Then 'image = table[volt]; LATGbits = image;'

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease amount of code on cost of  readability.

```
if (volt == 8 || volt == 9)  {
    LATGbits.LATG13 = 1;
    LATGbits.LATG14 = 0;
} else {
    LATGbits.LATG14 = 1;
    if (volt < 4) // 0,2,3
        LATGbits.LATG13 = 1;
    else //4,5,6,7,10
        LATGbits.LATG13 = 0;
}

if (volt % 2 == 1 || volt == 10)    // 3,5,7,9,10
    LATGbits.LATG1 = 1;
else    // 0,2,4,6,8
    LATGbits.LATG1 = 2;

if (volt == 2 || volt == 3 || volt == 6 || volt == 7)
    LATGbits.LATG0 = 0;
else //0,4,5,8,9,10
    LATGbits.LATG0 = 1;
```

Comment: Good call, can I know, what method to simplify like that ?

Comment: what does this means ? `volt % 2 == 1`

Comment: volt%2==1 means volt is odd

Answer (score 0):

Looking at comments in your code, it seems you want to use leds as a binary display (0 => OFF,OFF,OFF,OFF; 2 => OFF,OFF,ON,OFF; etc)

Looking at code, it seems that led D01 (LATGbits.LATG1) is controlled by ACTIVE-HIGH pin (the led is ON when the pin is "1"). Other leds are controlled by ACTIVE-LOW pin (the led is ON when the pin is "0"). So you have to take the "volt" value and invert bits 3,2 and 1 and leave bit 0 as is.

```
LATGbits.LATG1  = value & 1;  //D01
LATGbits.LATG0  = ~(value >> 1) & 1; //D02
LATGbits.LATG13 = ~(value >> 2) & 1; //D03
LATGbits.LATG14 = ~(value >> 3) & 1; //D04
```

Hope I understood your need.

P.S.: Just a little styling note: bits are numbered starting from 0 so it would be helpful if you number leds accordingly: D00, D01, D02, D03

Have a good work